# Upload Files >250MB via Sharepoint REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api

So I am trying to upload Files to a Sharepoint Site via the REST API. I am already using the /Files/Add() Path-Function, but that one is (from what I've found) per design locked to 250MB max and cannot be enlarged, but I would need to upload Files larger than that.

Is there any way I can do this with the Sharepoint REST API?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

`/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('{Path to File}')/startupload(uploadId={guid})`

`/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('{Path to File}')/continueupload(uploadId={guid}, fileOffset={Bytes uploaded until now})`

`/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('{Path to File}')/finishupload(uploadId={guid}, fileOffset={Bytes uploaded until now})`

continue and finish can have Chunks in there API-Body and after the upload is finished all of the chunks are added to the file.